# Form with fields from more than one model

Tags: python, django

I have a form that is based on the model User from django.contrib.auth.models

I have created another model called UserProfile which contains more information about the user.

In my forms.py I have a form that is based on:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
```

How can I show in my html the fields that is owned by UserProfile class?

PS.: In UserProfile class I have already created a field user = models.OneToOneField(User)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Muliple Models in a single django ModelForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/muliple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform)

Answer (score 3):

Create two forms and display them both in the same `<form>` tag. Then manually check whether the forms are valid and call `form.save()` on both of them. It's a bit more work but perhaps cleaner than merging them forcefully into one form.

([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/muliple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform))

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you need to look at is in-line forms. They cover it well for admin customization but the same principle applies when using ModelForms. Usually people just sub-class User?