# Creating one Django Form to save two models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the regular Django `User` model and a `UserDetails` model (`OneToOneField` with `User`), which serves as an extension to the `User` model. (I tried Django 1.5's feature and it was a headache with strangely horrible documentation, so I stuck with the `OneToOneField` option)

So, in my quest to build a custom registration page that will have a registration form comprised of the `User` fields and the `UserDetails` fields, I wondered if there was a way to generate the form automatically (with all of its validations) out of these two related models. I know this works for a form made of one model:

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

But is there anyway to get a similar functionality for a form comprised of two related models?

Comment: Yes there is, just make your own model form that you can extend in the init function with a custom save fn.

Comment: @Neal Can you please elaborate on that, with an example if possible, and post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I do not know how I can elaborate... The only thing I would put in an answer is exactly what is in my comment above...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Models in a single django ModelForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict, fields_for_model


class UserDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        _fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
        _initial = model_to_dict(instance.user, _fields) if instance is not None else {}
        super(UserDetailsForm, self).__init__(initial=_initial, instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(User, _fields))

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        u = self.instance.user
        u.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        u.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        u.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        u.save()
        profile = super(UserDetailsForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        return profile
```

Comment: looks good, but shouldn't class Meta: model = UserDetails and not model = UserDetailsForm ? Also, suppose UserDetails has a field called phoneNumber (with a regex for \d{10}) does the form automatically take care of that as you put it (because it's linked with the UserDetails model) or do I need to modify your code above? Thanks

Comment: sorry my mistake. You have to modified it because I only put common fields for user

Comment: I see. Two more questions: 1- If I have to add the custom UserDetails fields (such as phone), where should I make a reference to it in the above code, or will django do that for me automagically because class meta now points to UserDetails?  2- What about the other user fields (password, username)? Do I have to add them to your code or Django takes care of that?

Comment: 1 - you don't have to put the phone because the form meta is already point to UserDetails. 2 - you have to add password and username the way I add first_name, last_name, and email in __init__ function. So __init__ function is for your User model and meta is for your UserDetails model

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is clear. What about the validation of the email field for user (and making sure password1 equals password2) during registration? I assume I will do that too, right?

Comment: you can add clean_method() in the form

Comment: @catherine: I tried your solution, but it did not work, I have some issues that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171103/generating-user-and-userprofle-model-from-a-single-form-in-django

Comment: I'm curious how you would populate the ModelForm from a POST: `form = UserDetailForm(request.POST)` is not possible with that constructor.

Answer (score 6):

One way you can accomplish this, if you want to keep the ModelForm for User and UserDetails separate would be to return both forms to the front-end, and make sure they are both in the same html form element (i.e. all fields will be returned when data is posted).

This works if User and UserDetails don't have any fields with the same name. To input the data in each ModelForm instance, you use the usual method:

```
    form_user = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    form_user_details = UserDetailsForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userdetails)
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that the user still hasn't registered, wouldn't request.user point to nothing (or anonymous user)?

Comment: That is correct, it would point to AnonymousUser. I was just showing a case where you would re-use the form later.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate question uses this. In my opinion this is better as it leaves less potential for screw ups.