# Django: multiple values for keyword argument 'initial'

Tags: python, django

On Django I'm getting this traceback:

```
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/eeytan/ddragon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1085.             form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/dragon_portal/parentprofile/1/
Exception Value: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'instance'
```

For this code based on [Creating one Django Form to save two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889794/creating-one-django-form-to-save-two-models):

```
class ParentCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name   = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email       = forms.EmailField()
    #ice_contact = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    #notes       = HTMLField()

    def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        _fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
        _initial = model_to_dict(instance.dragonuser, _fields) \
            if instance is not None else {}
        kwargs['initial'] = _initial
        super(ParentCreationForm, self).__init__(instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(DragonUser, _fields))
```

As you can see, the signature of `__init__()` is not changed. Also, more strangely, Django's more detailed traceback shows that for each step in the traceback, the `argv` is *always*, `{}`, so I'm not even sure at what point of the traceback the error comes from.

Comment: what are the values of *args and `**kwargs`?  It seems like there is a key value pair for `instance` in `**kwargs`

Comment: can you show the view that is calling this piece of code too ?

Comment: Also, is the issue with `instance` or `initial` ?

Comment: Python says that the error is with "initial," which baffles me. Also, bypassing the `__imit__` completely, replacing it with a call to the `__init__` of the `super()` doesn't fix the error. HOWEVER, replacing the whole class with a generic UserCreationForm does work (after removing the fields I need). Let me fetch the view.

Comment: This is all in the admin, so it's just using the standard admin views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` function signature is incorrect for a ModelForm.

From the [Django source for BaseModelForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L291) you can see that the function signature is:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None):
```

So if anyone instantiates your form with an unnamed argument in the first position as Django does, then you'll end up with this error.

I'd suggest rewriting your `__init__` like this:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        _fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
        _initial = model_to_dict(instance.dragonuser, _fields) \
            if instance is not None else {}
        kwargs['initial'] = _initial
        super(ParentCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(DragonUser, _fields))
```

Comment: Happens some times!  Your answer is effectively the same, you get my vote.

Comment: And therefore you get mine!

Comment: @AustinPhillips I just figured it out after about four hours of trying. And as I was about to answer it myself, I found your answer. Still, congrats on figuring it out. I didn't change that part, mostly because I trusted the previous SO answer. Anyway, now, I can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Python won't let you spec a keyword argument for "instance" in the call to your init (as is being done in .../django/contrib/admin/options.py:1085) because the first argument in the call is getting mapped to "instance" due to the order of parameters and then the third parameter is also getting mapped to "instance" because of being spec'd as a keyword argument.

To fix this, remove `instance=None` from your `__init__` signature and instead in the first line of the method do this:

```
instance = kwargs.get("instance")
```

Also remove the `instance=instance` from the super call as instance should be carried in the kwargs now.