# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'instance'

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

I was tring to keep ckeditor and markdown at same time in a edit/(add new post) in blog web backend, so i modifid `__init__`,after that,i can still open edit page .but,once I click save button, this error came out:`TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'instance'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 604, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1640, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1525, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "E:\python_works\project\django\typeidea-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1556, in _changeform_view
    form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'instance'
```

this is the part where once i delete, error won't come out:

## blog/adminforms.py

```
class PostAdmin(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def __init__(self, instance=None, initial=None, **kwargs):
        initial = initial or {}
        if instance:
            if instance.is_md:
                initial['content_md'] = instance.content
            else:
                initial['content_ck'] = instance.content
        super().__init__(instance=instance, initial=initial, **kwargs)
    ....
```

Comment: If 'instance' is also define in your kwargs that you are passing, that would explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

I fonud solution here:
[Django: multiple values for keyword argument 'initial'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672035/django-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-initial)
It is a same problem as mine,generally speaking.somehow, the `instance` pass to`def __init__(self, instance=None, initial=None, **kwargs):` is not receive by `instance`,instead it passed to `kwargs`(still don't know why),then `intance` is default to be`None`,so there are two `inastance` parameters,the first instance which is default to be `None`,the second `instance`is in `kwargs` which is the real one i want to pass

so that what i done to fix it:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        initial = kwargs.get('initial') or {}
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            if instance.is_md:
                initial['content_md'] = instance.content
            else:
                initial['content_ck'] = instance.content
        kwargs.update({'instance':instance,'initial':initial})
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```