# single form from two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have a custom user model and a model photographer

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('First Name'), blank=True, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('Last Name'), blank=True, null=True)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Username'))
   email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name=_('Email Address'),
    unique=True,
   )
```

photographer

```
class Photographer(models.Model):
   state =models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('State'))
   city =models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('City'))
   zip_code =models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Zip Code'))
   hourly_rate =models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Hourly rate'))
   TRAVEL_CHOICES = ((2,'2km'),(5,'5km'),(10,'10km'),(25,'25km'),(50,'50km'))
   miles_travel = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TRAVEL_CHOICES)
   about_me =models.TextField(verbose_name=_('About Me'))
   photographer_user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User')
```

Can i populate the single form from these two models ?

Comment: Is this a 1 to 1 relationship between Photographer and User?

Comment: yes it is 1 to 1 relationship but a user may not be a photographer.

Comment: **I think you will find your answer here**



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889794/creating-one-django-form-to-save-two-models