# Django User model and Userprofile model in the same form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using the common pattren of using he Django User model while having a OneToOne relation via a Userprofile to extend the user.

I would like to have one view which allows me to set both User fields and UserProfile fields on the same form. It should apply both db transactions to User and Userprofile tables.

I would love to use the ModelForm however I dont find anyway that I can use two models in the same form.

How should I accomplish this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770810

Answer (score 2):

Create a model form for your user profile and add user related fields for user model e.g. `first_name` and `last_name` and save the user fields when profile model get saved:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField('First Name', max_length=25)
    last_name = forms.CharField('Last Name', max_length=25)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileModel
        exclude = ('user', )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        user = instance.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return instance
```