# Django forms.MultipleChoiceField only selects one value

Tags: python, django

I have a form with only one field which is a `MultipleChoiceField`. In the template it is being printed with two other forms that are `ModelForm`s inside the same HTML form (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774732/2183395)).

When reading all of the `POST` data in the view, everything is there and working correctly except the values from this `MultipleChoiceField`, which is shown only the last selected value from the form if selecting it straight from `request.POST['field']` -- but interesting enough, if I print `request.POST`, everything selected is there. How is this possible? This is really puzzling my mind.

This is the form:

```
class EstadosAtendidosForm(forms.Form):
    estadosSelecionados = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = choices.UF.list)
```

This is the view:

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def cadastro_transportadora(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        print len(request.POST['estadosSelecionados'])
        print request.POST
        estadosSelecionados = request.POST['estadosSelecionados']
        for estado in estadosSelecionados:
            print estado
        
        form_end = EnderecoForm(request.POST)
        form_transp = TransportadoraForm(request.POST)
        
        
        
    else:
        transportadora_form = TransportadoraForm()
        endereco_form = EnderecoForm()
        estados_form = EstadosAtendidosForm()
        return render(request, 'transporte/transportadora/cadastro.html', {'transportadora_form': transportadora_form, 'endereco_form': endereco_form, 'estados_form': estados_form})
```

And this is the template:

```
{% extends "transporte/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
<h1>Cadastro de Transportadora</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Dados da transportadora</h4>
    {{ transportadora_form.as_p }}
    <h4>Endereço</h4>
    {{ endereco_form.as_p }}
    <h4>Estados atendidos</h4>
    {{ estados_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The output from the prints in the view, since line 5 to 10, is as follows:

```
<QueryDict: {u'nome': [u'Test name'], u'bairro': [u'Estrela'], u'logradouro': [u'R. SHudhsu'], u'numero': [u'234'], u'estadosSelecionados': [u'AM', u'RJ', u'SP'], u'telefone': [u'+559965321232'], u'cep': [u'88088888'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'mQhxZlbosISw4acZOmTWw6FpaQPwg2lJ'], u'estado': [u'AM'], u'email': [u'test@email.com']}>
2
<QueryDict: {u'nome': [u'Test name'], u'bairro': [u'Estrela'], u'logradouro': [u'R. SHudhsu'], u'numero': [u'234'], u'estadosSelecionados': [u'AM', u'RJ', u'SP'], u'telefone': [u'+559965321232'], u'cep': [u'88088888'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'mQhxZlbosISw4acZOmTWw6FpaQPwg2lJ'], u'estado': [u'AM'], u'email': [u'test@email.com']}>
S
P
```

See that the variable `estadosSelecionados` really contains the 3 values that I selected from the form, correctly, as a list, when I print the whole `request.POST` data, but when I print just `request.POST['estadosSelecionados']`, it doesn't.

Why?

Answer (score 8):

`POST` is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object, which has special behavior when multiple values are submitted in the HTTP POST for the same key. To get all of them, use the [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method. Alternatively, just use your form - the form field will collect the multiple values for you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be looking in request.POST. The whole point of using a form is that it takes care of things like type conversion. Look in `form.cleaned_data['estadosSelecionados']` after checking `form.is_valid()`.