# Django - Display fields from different models in one form

Tags: python, django

Say I have two different models like...

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Model2(models.Model):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

However, upon a sign up form for example I want them to input information that corresponds to **field1, field2 and field3** of course which spreads over two separate models.

**forms.py**

```
class Form1 (forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Model1, Model2 #note that this does not work...:(
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
```

How can I get this to work so that I can receive data from two different models on the same one form?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform). Basically just make two `ModelForm` classes and render them both on the page. A `ModelForm` is meant for only one model

Comment: You can send multiple forms from your view to your template.

Comment: Create a fake model with all required fields from both models and implement save method to fill and save your "real" models