# How do I populate FOREIGN KEY with a Django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to give the user the ability to enter data 
here is my models named cv :

```
class Experience_Pro(models.Model):
    annee_debut = models.IntegerField()
    annee_fin = models.IntegerField()
    description_exp_pro = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

class Ecole(models.Model):
    nom_ecole = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classement = models.IntegerField()

class Academic(models.Model):
    annee_debut = models.IntegerField()
    annee_fin = models.IntegerField()
    type_diplome = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description_academic = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    ecole = models.ForeignKey('Ecole' , on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Cv(models.Model):
    experience_Pro = models.ForeignKey('Experience_Pro' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    academic = models.ForeignKey('Academic',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here is my form

```
class CvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Cv     
        fields = "__all__"
```

but instead of getting inputs for the user to enter data i get a dropdownlist of already existed records in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is the way django is designed when using a ModelForm.

Realistically, you can create two model forms from the Experience & Academic models and join them in the view.

[Multiple Models in a single django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform)

Answer (score 0):

Your cv model doesnt have any fields for input. You are only have the relation with other model as a foreignkey relation. This way you can only access the data here not create one