# Create multiple entries for one model in a Django modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

Sorry if the title is confusing, I can't really think of how else to word it.

I am creating a site where there are many quizzes. Each `Quiz` model

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    num_questions = models.IntegerField(default = 10)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 20)
    img = models.URLField(blank = True) # allow it to be none

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()
```

looks like this... and it has some attributes like name, description, etc. There are many `Question` models that have `ForeignKey` to one `Quiz`:

```py
class Question(models.Model):

    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    img = models.URLField(blank = True) # allow none`
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
    
    def get_answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()
```

and then there are some `Choice` models that have `ForeignKey` to one `Question`:

```py
class Choice(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    content = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Now. I want to create one single `ModelForm` from which I can create 1 quiz record, and then 10 question records with 4 choice records per question. It would be very nice if they could automatically set their foreignkey to the Question that is being created. How can I go about this? Is it even possible? I don't even know if my wording of this question is making sense because I have a great big idea in my head but no idea how to express it properly in words or code.

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use model_formset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 models and you want to show them in a single form in your HTML file. Then you can simply create a model form for each of them and add them in a single `<form>` tag.

The answer to a similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774732/15581055).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean inserting multiple records at the same time, then consider looking at formset factory - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/